# Consulta sin datos repetidos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

Verán necesito mandar a pedir una cantidad *n* de preguntas, en donde esa cantidad está dada por un parámetro. La consulta ya es funcional y las manda a traer con dicho parámetro de forma aleatoria.

Lo que ocurre ahora es que muestra preguntas que son repetidas, y debería mostrar preguntas únicas, por tanto estuve viendo algunas cosas de `SELECT DISTINCT` pero no sé bien cómo implementarlo ya que existe ya una sentencia `SELECT TOP`.

Aquí está la consulta, está hecha en `SQL Server 2012`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spListarPreguntasPorTema]
(@prmLimite int,
@prmCodTema int
)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP (@prmLimite) p.cod_pregunta, p.pregunta
        FROM dbo.pregunta AS p
        INNER JOIN dbo.tema AS t
        ON p.cod_tema = @prmCodTema AND @prmLimite = t.no_preguntas
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    END
```

Comment: Puedes agregar un `GROUP BY` por ejemplo, de modo que agrupe por el identificador único del dato que no quieres repetir si lo tuviera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te marca el error porque todos aquellos campos que vayas a agrupar los debes especificar en el `GROUP BY`, en este caso te haría falta agregarle el campo `cod_pregunta`. El problema que tendrías es que si el campo `cod_pregunta` es un valor único o `unique`, te va a seguir repitiendo los resultados. Tu consulta quedaría mas o menos así:

```
  SELECT TOP (@prmLimite) p.cod_pregunta, p.pregunta
    FROM dbo.pregunta AS p
    INNER JOIN dbo.tema AS t
    ON p.cod_tema = @prmCodTema AND @prmLimite = t.no_preguntas
    GROUP BY p.cod_pregunta, p.pregunta
    ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Aunque no me queda claro porque haces un `JOIN` con el parámetro `@prmCodTema`, creo que sería mas eficiente hacer un `WHERE p.cod_tema = @prmCodTema`. Por otro lado el `@prmLimite = t.no_preguntas` en tu `JOIN` tampoco entiendo muy bien para que lo haces. Quizás si colocaras la estructura de tus tablas pudiéramos ayudarte mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Es cierto, me faltaba agregarle ése campo. Ahora me funcionó bien, ¡Muchas gracias!